# Prototype pattern with Generics instead of clonable

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, clone, prototype-pattern

I've been reading the GoF patterns book and I'm wondering if using generics would achieve the same results as using the prototype pattern's conventional clone implementation. 
Maybe I'm not understanding the prototype pattern correctly so let me know if what's happening there is not the prototype pattern.

As far as I understand the prototype pattern is basically instead of creating different factories for different subclasses u pass the subclass to the factory in the constructor so that it instantiates the subclasses from that blueprint.

In the below example 
I set the type of objects this factory should return as a generic and instantiate it when calling make item.

Example:

```
public class PrototypedFactory {
    Prototype prototype;

    public PrototypedFactory(Prototype prototype) {

        this.prototype = prototype;
    }

    public Prototype makeItem() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Prototype) prototype.clone();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GenericFactory<ConcretePrototype> factoryGeneric = new GenericFactory<ConcretePrototype>(
                ConcretePrototype.class);
        PrototypedFactory factory = new PrototypedFactory(new ConcretePrototype());

        Prototype item = factory.makeItem();
        Prototype item2 = factoryGeneric.makeItem();
        System.out.println(item.getName());
        System.out.println(item2.getName());
    }

}
```

GenericFactory:

```
public class GenericFactory<T extends Prototype> {
    Class<T> c;

    public GenericFactory(Class<T> clazz) {
        c = clazz;
    }

    public Prototype makeItem() throws Exception {
        return c.newInstance();
    }

}
```

Prototype:

```
public abstract class Prototype implements Cloneable {
    String name = "prototype";

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind prototype is that you can configure the prototype object any way you want, and you'll always get perfect copies. You can't achieve that with generics, so a clone-like approach is required.

It also doesn't have anything to do with subclasses in its pure form. You're mixing up factories and prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a *generic factory* which can instantiates objects of the generic type it is initialized with. Your design is thus an improvement over creating multiple factory classes for multiple types of objects which are to be cloned - to now creating multiple objects types using the same factory class.

**Its the factory which is generic. Prototyping has not been achieved through generics.**

Prototype pattern, on the other hand, is concentrated on *how to create copies of objects from existing objects by cloning*. Factories just give us an elegant way to create those clones.

If things are still unclear, you can refer an article I have written on Prototype pattern in my blog -http://www.javabrahman.com/design-patterns/prototype-design-pattern-in-java/ .